# Get recent wordpress posts in Laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel, posts

I have a Wordpress site and a Laravel site and I want to display recent wordpress posts in the footer of Laravel site. How can I do this without having my wordpress database information in my config/database.php file and using it in the models? Can I get them using RSS?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the posts by calling an API endpoint:

**yoursiteurl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts**

It will return all the posts in a json format. You can also see the reference from [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/).

Comment: You can use file_get_content instead in side the function of model or controller whereever you want.

Comment: $result_from_json = file_get_contents('yoursiteurl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
$dataArr=json_decode($result_from_json,true );

print_r($dataArr); //print in array

Comment: I'm getting " You don't have permission to access /wp-json/wp/v2/posts on this server. " error!

Comment: First you try that url in browser and let me know what exactly showing

Comment: It's showing "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /wp-json/wp/v2/posts on this server."

Comment: add it define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'your-top-secrect-key'); wp-config.php //anything you want but unique.

Comment: Where and how to use defined secret key?

Comment: Just paste the code into wp-config.php [ your-top-secrect-key = anything unique ]

Comment: Did it and still have the issue

Comment: I have the issue even when I'm logged in to my wordpress site!

Comment: set the permalink to Post name and check it again

Answer (score 2):

Recent WordPress was released with a huge thing called REST API – earlier it was possible only with external plugins. So now we can query WordPress database from external projects. Including Laravel.

set up a local WordPress website, and after installation you got that usual dashboard.

we can already make API calls after installation. No need to configure anything, we just launch the URL in the browser:

we’ve received a JSON with a list of posts – by default, WordPress creates one dummy post.
Basically, URL structure for the API calls is simple:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/[endpoint]?[parameters]
```

Yes, you’ve read it right, we can get posts, categories, tags and other things that are publicly available, so we don’t need any authentication here.

And we also can filter the data with GET parameters, like this:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=2&orderby=title
```

For more details open link:- [Using WordPress REST API in Laravel](https://laraveldaily.com/using-wordpress-rest-api-laravel/)